# Audio on J2ME, I don't know where is wrong?

Tags: java, audio, java-me, inputstream

I want to do 2 task at same time:

- Play an audio file.
- Read raw data of it to do something

Here is my code:

```
String wavPath = "file:///" + currentPath + fileName;
FileConnection fc;
try {
    fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open( wavPath );

    if ( !fc.exists() ) {
        throw new IOException( "File does not exists." );
    }

    InputStream is = fc.openInputStream();
    // to do something with raw data as print samples of it

    Player player = Manager.createPlayer( wavPath );
    player.realize();
    player.prefetch();
    player.start();
} catch ( IOException e1 ) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

But nothing run, audio file doesn't not run. If I remove line:

```
InputStream is = fc.openInputStream();
```

Audio file run very well. But I want to do 2 task at same time, i don't know how to do it. Anybody can help me ?

I have tried use 2 thread, but it still doesn't work, audio file run (thread 1) but thread 2 not run:

```
new Thread( new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Manager.createPlayer( "file:///E:/" + fileName ).start();
        } catch ( MediaException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();

new Thread( new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        FileConnection fc;
        try {
            fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open( "file:///E:/" + fileName );
            InputStream is = fc.openInputStream();

            byte[] b = new byte[10];
            int length = is.read( b, 0, 10 );
            for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
                form.append( b[i] + "" );
            }
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: I want to play wave file (.wav)

Comment: The only reason that I can see that it will work when you remove that line is that the 'main' thread is blocking on that call while attempting to open the input stream. Do you get an exception after a period of time?

Comment: I'd try to simulate behavior like you describe using two copies of the file. Play audio from 1st copy and read 2nd. As long as user does not notice that you cheat that way, who cares?

Answer (score 3):

why don't you use threading... 
create a thread to play the wav file
and use another thread to do read a file...

refer [here](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/threading2/) for further details on threading in J2ME

---

```
public class View_PlayMidlet extends MIDlet {

    PlayerThread musicPlayer = new PlayerThread();

    public void startApp() {
        String fileName = "file://e:/abcd.wav";
        musicPlayer.setPlayableFile(fileName);
        FileConnection fc = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        String fileContent = null;
        try {
            fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///E:/" + fileName);
            is = fc.openInputStream();

            byte[] b = new byte[10];
            int length = is.read(b, 0, 10);

            fileContent = new String(b);

            // display the content of fileContent variable in a form.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
            if (fc != null) {
                try {
                    fc.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
            }
        }
        // by this time the file is displayed & you can start playing the file.
        Thread t = new Thread(musicPlayer);
        t.start();

    }

    public void pauseApp() {
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    }
}

public class PlayerThread implements Runnable {

    private String fileName;
    private Player player;

    public PlayerThread() {
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            player = Manager.createPlayer(fileName);
            player.prefetch();
            player.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopMusic() {
        try {
            player.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setPlayableFile(String fileName) {
        this.fileName=fileName;
    }
}
```

this would roughly be what you are looking for.

Comment: I have tried 2 thread, but it still doesn't work. I have update my code in above main question. Please help me!

Comment: try to prefetch the content...
`
            Player p=Manager.createPlayer( "file:///E:/"+fileName );
            p.prefetch();
            p.start();
 `

also i think the player needs exclusive access to the file while its playing it... try to read a different file in thread 2 & check it.

Comment: I try to read an other audio file, the code work, but I want to read and play in same file. Any solution for me ?

Comment: well thats how the player is built... it requires exclusive access to the file its playing... may be you can display the file content first & play the file afterwards... (only thing to do is to play with the sequence of thread execution).

Comment: Your code is very clear and work. But if I want to read data of file continuous, and while player are playing, data is written, how I have to do ? Because data is too large, so that I have to divide it and read each part.

Answer (score 2):

Your Player instances are garbage collected. Also, file access during playback will likely be 'implementation specific', meaning that it will work on some models and not others. So read the data first, copy it to another file etc, if you want something solid.

You can always [go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274335/using-datasource-in-j2me) the [DataSource](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr135/javax/microedition/media/protocol/DataSource.html)-path too.